# Is it possible if two different objects have the same hashcode? Does it means they are the same?

Tags: flutter, object, hashcode, cloning

I have a class

```dart
class Controller with EquatableMixin {
  final int id;
  //... other props

  Controller.from(Controller controller) :   
    id = controller.id,
    //... other props assignments

  List<Object> props => [
    id,
    //... other props
  ];
}

final ctrl1 = Controller(...); // Create ctrl1
final ctrl2 = Controller.from(ctrl1); // Create ctrl2 (actually clonning)
assert(ctrl1.hasCode != ctrl2.hasCode); // triggered!
```

I expected that `ctrl1` and `ctrl2` are different objects with different `hashCode`s but they have the same `hashCode`. Why? How can I be assure that `ctrl12` is not pointer to `ctrl2`?

Comment: Please post your real code, preferably a [mcve]. It's hard to see where you might be off when you post a rough estimate of what your code might look like.

Comment: You are using `equatable`. The whole point of this package is to override `hashCode`/`==` such that two objects with the same content have the same hashCode/==

Comment: Guys, thanks for you both for explanation. Usually I used hashCode for knowing if I used the correct object which maybe "come" from outside. And usually it helps... :) But it looks like I was misled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "Hashcode" is a definition. You decide what hashcode your objects have. A hashcode should *not* be used to find out if two objects are actually the same memory instance.

Obviously two distinct objects can have the same hashcode:

```
int i = 5;
int x = 5;
```

They should have the same hashcode, after all, they are the same value. It's still two distinct variables.

---

A hashcode also says nothing about whether two objects are equal. The only statement it makes is that two objects with *different* hashcodes are **not** equal. Two objects of the same hashcode are not equal until you checked whether they are. They *might* be equal. A hashcode is a way to reduce the number of actual equality checks you have to make, not a way to determine if something actually is equal.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have two objects with the same hashcode.

Here's an example:

```dart
void main() {
  print(1.hashCode); // 1
  print(''.hashCode); // 1
}
```

`1` and `''` are obviously two different objects but have the same hashcode.

In fact, all objects could have the same hashcode that it shouldn't have an impact on the behavior of your project (besides performance).
Do not use hashCodes to compare objects.